# Table createCell ignore one column

Tags: codenameone

I was testing my app before launching an update and I found something that I really don't understand:

One of my forms include a editable `Table` with pinestripe effect and a custom `TableModel` that is nearly a copy of the `DefaultTableModel` (needed access to private fields). Everything was working fine some weeks ago.

Now the second of my columns is ignored by the `createCell` overrided method. I've put a log at the start of the method, showing value, row and column and the column 1 only trigger this when building the columns titles. All other columns trigger the log, but never the column 1.

Any idea of anything that can cause this behavior ?

Thanks in advance.

[image: The culprit column is Qtty]

EDIT: Here is the overrided createCell code:

```
@Override
protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {
    Component cell;
    Log.p("Table CreateCell "+ row + " " + column + " " + value + " " + editable);

    if(editable && (column == 1 || column == 2 || column == 3) && row != -1) 
    {
        //Table is editable
        Component TA = new TextArea(value.toString());
        TA.setUIID(CerebroMobileTheme.LABEL);
        ((TextArea)TA).setEditable(DocFormLineTable.this.editable);
        TA.setEnabled(DocFormLineTable.this.editable);
        if(column == 1) //Quantity cells
            ((TextArea)TA).setHint("Qtty");
        if(column == 2) //Description cells
            ((TextArea)TA).setHint("Description");
        if(column == 3)
        {
            //Third columns cells are confirm buttons
            TA = new Button("");
            TA.setUIID("BlueButton");
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon((Button)TA, FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK);
            ((Button)TA).addActionListener(e-> {
                //Similar code is used at the closing of the form to save data
                //DocFormLine is a line of data for our document
                DocFormLine dfl = (DocFormLine)value;
                dfl.setDescription(((TextArea)((TableLayout)this.getLayout()).getComponentAt(row+1, 2)).getText());
                dfl.setQtty(Double.parseDouble(((TextArea)((TableLayout)this.getLayout()).getComponentAt(row+1, 1)).getText()));
                //Call our rest service to save the data serverside
                RestManager.saveDocFormLine(dfl);
            });
        }
        cell = TA;

    } 
    else 
    {
        //If non editable or title or first columns(non editable field), cell set to a SpanLabel
        cell = new SpanLabel((String)value);
        cell.setUIID("label");
        if(column == 3)
            cell = new Label("");
    }
}
```

Here is the Log result from the creation of the Table :

```
[EDT] 0:0:21,387 - Table CreateCell -1 0 Produit false
[EDT] 0:0:21,388 - Table CreateCell -1 1 Qtty false
[EDT] 0:0:21,388 - Table CreateCell -1 2 Utilisation false
[EDT] 0:0:21,388 - Table CreateCell -1 3  false
[EDT] 0:0:21,388 - Table CreateCell 0 0 Main d'oeuvre et déplacements true
[EDT] 0:0:21,388 - Table CreateCell 0 2  true
[EDT] 0:0:21,388 - Table CreateCell 0 3 ***.entities.DocFormLine@6ac641c6 true
[EDT] 0:0:21,391 - Table CreateCell 1 0 Main d'oeuvre et déplacements true
[EDT] 0:0:21,391 - Table CreateCell 1 2  true
[EDT] 0:0:21,391 - Table CreateCell 1 3 ***.entities.DocFormLine@69cdb35a true
```

With the help of the Log, I've determined that the column 1 only trigger the createCell method when creating the column title.

Comment: I'll need to see the code but I'm guessing the UIID is changed after you've set it for this specific cell

Comment: The problem is not really about theming the table, but more about the Qtty cells that are null instead of being a `Textfield`. The createCell is not called at all for these cells, that's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any code that blocks create cell if the value is null. But maybe it creates a blank label which is then hidden. Try doing something like this:

```
protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {        
    // initialize the cell... all of your current code

    if(cell instanceof Label) {
        ((Label)cell).setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hello Shai, I've added the Log that is produced at the start of the method to my question, I've should have done that from the start, sorry. I know that the cell component is null, even if it's value is not, because later in the code, when I save the data, I try to get the new value of the cell, and encounter an NPE because the cell is null.

Comment: The cell value might be null but the cell component never will be. BTW in your else statement at the bottom I see you create a span label with "label" UIID (lower case l?). Wouldn't that be the reason? Did you step through a debugger and see that the right label is created. If the value of the cell is null and the UIID is correct then my answer above should work

Comment: I've just add some logger after the initialisation of the table, in order to Log each Cell of the table to be sure, and the Cell is really null, the value is not null, but the cell component is. For the lower case "label" UIID it's just a mistake while editing the method.

Comment: I've push my test further in the code, sorry to have bothered you, my Double to BigDecimal function was not ready for the last update of the CN1JSON lib, so the value were null, instead of being 0... Thanks for your help ! But I still don't understand why the create cell is not called if the value is null ^^

Comment: I see the code that blocks null entries now. I think null is a special case in table for spanning of cells. So I guess we don't support null cells after all